# How disable JFrame Background

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe

I've made a JFrame with the next Properties:

```
setLayout(null)
setUndecorated(true)
setResizable(false)
```

within i've put a JLabel with one Icon(PNG image) in netbeans, and im looking for some soluction that disable the backgroud(full Transparent, and unactive) when the mouse moves THROUGH JFrame's Image(or someother component) BUT the mouse works different outside of the JLabel because JLabel Icon avoid any mouse action over the JLabel. But there's a default Gray background that doesnt exactly what i want.

We can see that mouse doesnt do anything on the JLabel(unless there were some component in the Frame)

[image: http://i.picasion.com/resize80/48739d7f666d30ca2e5ecb818cc21d9d.jpg]

*Green = JFrame size.*

And here the mouse change when moves through of the web page

[image: http://i.picasion.com/resize80/f5d557001fba98d339957373de9ce89c.jpg]

Comment: Add a container (like `JPanel`) to the `JFrame`.

Comment: i did but doesn't work :(

Comment: Searched google https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+java+jpanel+background&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 1):

> im looking for some soluction that disable the backgroud(full Transparent, and unactive) when the mouse moves

Don't use full transparency.

If the pixels are not 100% transparent, then the MouseEvents will be handled by the frame.